# Convert a double to NSNumber in Swift

Tags: swift

How do I convert a `double` to `NSNumber` in Swift?

I tried

```
let myDouble = 7.12
NSNumber(myDouble)
```

But got the error:

> Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads

Comment: Use this constructor `init(value:)` as `let number = NSNumber.init(value: myDouble)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`init(value:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumber/1407545-init)

```
let nsNumber = NSNumber(value: myDouble)
```

or simply a cast

```
let nsNumber = myDouble as NSNumber
```

Answer (score 2):

Please, please let Xcode help you. Type `NSNumber(` and read the suggestions

[image]

Or <kbd>⌃⌘-click</kbd> on `NSNumber` to open the header file

Or read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnumber)